# Set CurrentUser (jwt) to @Post (in events controller)

Tags: postgresql, typescript, react-redux, typeorm

When a user makes an event
the logged in users id should be saved to the database

there is relation

```
  @ManyToOne(_ => User, user => user.events, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true
  })
  users: User;
```

in the events entity (many events possibly to one user)

my users entity relation

```
  @OneToMany(_ => Event, event => event.users, {
    eager: false
  })
  events: Event[];
```

in the database, all the fields (primary ID, name, description, image, startDate, endDate) show up plus a users_id. 
That supposedly should take in the logged in users ID

the events controller has an

```
@Post decorator

  @Authorized()
  @Post("/events")
  @HttpCode(201)
  createEvent(@Body() event: Event) {
    return event.save();
  }
```

and in the front-end 
my action sends all the values for the fields in the database 
(when I create an event al the values are stored)

```
export const addEvent = event => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();
  const jwt = state.currentUser.jwt;

  if (isExpired(jwt)) return dispatch(logout());

  request
    .post(`${baseUrl}/events`)
    .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwt}`)
    .send({
      name: event.name,
      description: event.description,
      startDate: event.startDate,
      endDate: event.endDate,
      image: event.image
    })
    .then(response =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_EVENT,
        payload: response.body
      })
    );
};
```

I also send a jwt for the currentUser

and I have an example coming from 
a boilerplate we got for learning to work with web-sockets

```
  @Authorized()
  @Post("/games/:id([0-9]+)/players")
  @HttpCode(201)
  async joinGame(@CurrentUser() user: User, @Param("id") gameId: number) {
    const game = await Game.findOneById(gameId);
    if (!game) throw new BadRequestError(`Game does not exist`);
    if (game.status !== "pending")
      throw new BadRequestError(`Game is already started`);

    game.status = "started";
    await game.save();

    const player = await Player.create({
      game,
      user,
      symbol: "o"
    }).save();

    io.emit("action", {
      type: "UPDATE_GAME",
      payload: await Game.findOneById(game.id)
    });

    return player;
  }
```

there when a new game is created 
it also stores the user that created the game

So I figured that it has something to do with the
@CurrentUser() user: User

But I have no Idea
how to implement in this projects @Post eventsController

If somebody can tell me how 
and with a short explanation of how and why that works 
I will keep googling.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the @Post

to

```
  @Authorized()
  @Post('/events')
  @HttpCode(201)
  async createEvent(
    @CurrentUser() user: User,
    @Body() event: Event,
  ) {
    if (user instanceof User) event.users = user

    const entity = event.save()
    return { entity }
  }
}
```

and apparently it needed a 
currentUserChecker function

```
currentUserChecker: async (action: Action) => {
    const header: string = action.request.headers.authorization
    if (header && header.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      const [, token] = header.split(' ')

      if (token) {
        const { id } = verify(token)
        return User.findOne(id)
      }
    }
    return undefined
  }
```

and I had to change the jwt.ts

from

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET || '9u8nnjksfdt98*(&*%T$#hsfjk'
const ttl = 3600 * 4 // our JWT tokens are valid for 4 hours

interface JwtPayload {
    id: number
}

export const sign = (data: JwtPayload) =>
    jwt.sign({ data }, secret, { expiresIn: ttl })

export const verify = (token: string): { data: JwtPayload } =>
    jwt.verify(token, secret) as { data: JwtPayload }
```

to

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET || '9u8nnjksfdt98*(&*%T$#hsfjk'
const ttl = 3600 * 4 // our JWT tokens are valid for 4 hours

interface JwtPayload {
    id: number
}

export const sign = (data: JwtPayload) =>
    jwt.sign({ data }, secret, { expiresIn: ttl })

export const verify = (token: string):  JwtPayload  =>
    jwt.verify(token, secret) as  JwtPayload
```